# Decoding JSON object and mapping the values to a struct in Go

Tags: go, struct

I have created a webserver using the library net http. My problem is that I want to create a Struct like below from a JSON object, whose keys names don't match with the struct attributes.

```
type JsonData struct {
    Operation     string
    IsStaff       int
}
```

The JSON object sent from the server is:

```
{
    "function": "search",
    "is_staff": 1
    "description": "Test"
}
```

Most of the solutions I have found are creating another struct, where the JSON keys and struct attribute names match each other. Is there a way to map the JSON decoded to my JsonData struct? Below it is my current function right now.

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    switch r.Method {   
        case http.MethodPost:
            var data JsonData
             err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&data)
     }
 }
```

Comment: Use struct tags. They're covered in the `encoding/json` documentation, and most posts on SO regarding JSON and Go.

Answer (score 1):

Search for "tag" in the [`json.Marshal` documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal).

Basically, you can tag struct fields with special annotations that tell the default un/marshaler to use the given name instead of the (case-insensitive) name of the struct field.

For your struct you can likely just do the following, depending on your actual intent:

```
type JsonData struct {
  Operation string `json:"function"`
  IsStaff   int    `json:"is_staff"`
}

func main() {
  jsonstr := `{"function":"search","is_staff":1,"description":"Test"}`

  var jd JsonData
  err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonstr), &jd)

  fmt.Printf("OK: jd=%#v, err=%v\n", jd, err)
  // OK: jd=main.JsonData{Operation:"search", IsStaff:1}, err=<nil>
}
```